# Classe java com float e int

Tags: java, mvc, classes, eclipse, controller

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto MVC com Java para web utilizando eclipse.

Na tabela produto de banco de dados está assim

```
       create table Produto
(
    Idproduto int identity primary key,
    Nome varchar(40),
    Preco decimal(6,2),
    Categoria int,
    Estoque int
    
    )
```

}

Tenho uma classe chamada produto

```
public class Produto {

private int Idproduto;
private String Nome;
private float Preco;
private int Categoria;
private int Estoque;
public int getIdproduto() {
    return Idproduto;
}
public void setIdproduto(int idproduto) {
    Idproduto = idproduto;
}
public String getNome() {
    return Nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    Nome = nome;
}
public float getPreco() {
    return Preco;
}
public void setPreco(float preco) {
    Preco = preco;
}
public int getCategoria() {
    return Categoria;
}
public void setCategoria(int categoria) {
    Categoria = categoria;
}
public int getEstoque() {
    return Estoque;
}
public void setEstoque(int estoque) {
    Estoque = estoque;
}
public Produto() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Produto(int idproduto, String nome, float preco, int categoria, int estoque) {
    super();
    Idproduto = idproduto;
    Nome = nome;
    Preco = preco;
    Categoria = categoria;
    Estoque = estoque;
}
```

Função inserir produto

```
public void Inserirproduto(Produto produto) {
        
        try {
            Connection con = conectar();
            CallableStatement cls = con.prepareCall("{call Inserirprodutoadm(?,?,?,?)}");
            cls.setString(1, produto.getNome());
            cls.setFloat(2, produto.getPreco());
            cls.setInt(3, produto.getCategoria());
            cls.setInt(4, produto.getEstoque());
            cls.execute();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Quando chamo essa classe no controller com os tipos de dados int e float ele não reconhece

[image: Código]

Como faço para os tipos int e float ser reconhecidos quando chama a classe ?

Comment: Opa, voocê precisa dar um parse nessa: Integer.parseInt(str);
Float.parseFloat(str);

Comment: Valeu amigao. Deu certo aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um parse, exemplo:

```
produto.setPreco(Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Preco")); //para Float
produto.setCategoria(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Categoria"))) // Para Int
```